# Batch Rename Files based on list

Tags: batch-file, filenames

Here is my problem. I have 7 template forms. Each of my customers requires a form created for their file. For example, my customer Jon would require: Jon_Marks, Jon_Evaluation, Jon_Comments. Tina would need the exact same files, but with her name.

Is there a way, to create a bat file, that can auto-rename for me, where it gets the names from a txt file and inserts the value at the beginning of the filename?

Comment: This is without a txt file as input but for 7 different options I would stick to this: http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool

Comment: What format are looking for in the output file? (ie: xls, csv, txt)

Answer (score 0):

The following may accomplish what you are looking for. It uses a for loop to iterate through the text files and makes a "call" to another bit of the batch file to do the rename and increment of a variable.

```
@echo off
set i=1
for %%f in (*.txt) do call :renameit "%%f"
goto done

:renameit
ren %1 %i%.txt
set /A i+=1

:done
```